Broken Texture Shading?
I had to fix some topology on a model but now my texture seems really broken, almost like the shading is completely off. How can I fix this?




You would probably have a better chance of getting some help if you could add wireframe images of before and after. Or better yet, upload your .blend file with this object to https://blend-exchange.com/ and add it to your question.

both things i'd say.

I have added the Blend file.

The split normals (the normals that manage the shading) seem to have been messed up, reset the split normals with a Clear Custom Split Normals Data:

Also give your object a modifier Normals > Smooth by Angle, set the desired Angle:

Result:


I can't thank you enough, this worked perfect.

You’ve probably messed up the UV maps in the retopologizing. You can learn about UV maps and how they work here. You need to reproduce similar UV maps to what you had initially for the texture to work the same way (and no, this has nothing to do with shading). A Data Transfer modifier on the new mesh, pointing at the old one, copying / imitating the old UVs in the new mesh, will likely do the job. You may have to put the two objects in the same location for this to work, I don’t recall, but once it’s working you can apply the modifier and delete the old object.
